# What do you call plucking the violin strings with the finger, rather than using the bow?

Tags: theory, sheet-music, terminology, violin, string-instruments

I was attempting to learn a bit about violin sheet music, and then I wondered if the act of producing sound with the finger or the fingernail had a written notation.

I had a hard time finding a video with someone actually doing it. I found a large one, so I chopped it - here: http://www.tubechop.com/watch/1082408 (he does it twice).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This technique is called *Pizzicato*. It's usually notated by just writing *"pizz."* above the notes that you are to play that way. The opposite off *Pizzicato* is *Arco* which simply means to use the bow.

Comment: Linguistic note: Pizzicato is italian for “plucked” or “pinched”

Comment: My reference also gives "loco" as notation for "back to normal" (i.e. arco); however the main use of "loco" is to switch back to pitch as notated after an octavation passage.

Answer (score 13):

Just to elaborate and clarify, there are a few different types of pizzicato:

- There is the standard "pizz." which is done with the flesh of the finger on the bowing hand;
- A pizz with fingernail, which gives a more crisp attack;
- A "Bartok" or "snap" pizz where the performer pulls the string away from the fingerboard and releases to produce a harsh snapping sound;
- A left hand pizz which performers may do while performing simple or thoughtfully written passages;
- There is also strumming, which is notated with "pizz", an arrow to show direction, and usually an indication of "quasi chitara".

I thought it important to mention these things because the OP included the word "fingernail" in their question, and that is a specific type of sound that is *not* the standard pizzicato (in that it would need indication.)

Comment: Does left-hand pizz always have its own notation? I thought it was sometimes a used when both (1) the length of time between arco-pizz-arco was insufficient to pluck with the right hand and (2) the pizz was possible with the left?

Comment: Left-hand pizz is usually a + sign above the note. You can see Hilary Hahn alternate between arco (bowed) and pizz in Paganini's Caprice No 24 at 3:07 - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpC8LVAmxM8